# Как лучше сказать

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Первое время ты все время плакал..." или лучше "В первое время..."?

Comment: Возможно и так, и так. Полагаю, что будет немножко отличаться смысл, но чтобы это уловить нужно быть носителем языка.

Comment: А кто тут не носитель?

На самом деле проблема стилистическая есть, но она в повторе "времени".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, предлог не нужен. "Первое время" уже само по себе означает некоторый временной диапазон, *в котором* что-то там происходит.